# Firebase realtime database timestamp query - iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an **iOS** app that is quite similar to a chatting app with multiple chat rooms, mainly dependent on Firebase realtime database. I'm trying to query for new members who join any of the user's available rooms. I am doing this by observing a time stamp node in the rooms' participants database reference.

A sample of the participants' database reference:

[image]

Here is the query I use:

```
query = self.membersDatabaseReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp").queryStarting(atValue: lastMemberTimeStamp)
```

The problem is that the query's behaviour is inconsistent due to the difference between the timestamp value on the remote database and local server value of the firebase SDK. In other words that would cause for some old data to be retrieved and sometimes all old data to be retrieved.

Comment: your database reference link is not working

Comment: The single line of code you shared is not enough to allow us to say what's going on. Please ensure your question contains the [minimal, complete/standalone code that we can run to reproduce the problem you're having](;http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv) (read the link please, as it's quite useful). You'll want to include the actual observer closure code, typically with some print statement that shows the problem. If you then include the output of that print statement in both the correct case, and the problematic case, you'll have a better chance that we may be able to help.